# Transparent UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ipod

I am creating an iOS application in which I have added a simple UIImage. I want to add the transparency effect in image to show other images behind that main image. Tell me how I can achieve this effect?

**Note:** I don't want to change the opacity/alpha of image.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An alpha change is how you alter transparency. In addition to this, you would want to alter this on the view level not on to the `UIImage` directly. E.x:

```
[myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed@"myImage.png"]];
[myImageView setAlpha:0.7f];
```

Answer (score 2):

use images in png format with alpha channel in it: alpha channel is the layer that tells how many transparent each pixel is

Answer (score 2):

how about this:

```
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,1024.0f,768.0f)];
self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:255 blue:255 alpha:0.5];
[self.view addSubview:self.imageView];

or set its alpha
imageView.alpha = 0.5;
```

But be sure to instantiate the imageView, as property then synthesize.